# Cannot get description content using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php

I am trying to get all the description from this eBay url: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Front-strut-spacers-30mm-for-Ford-Focus2-C-Max-Focus3-Kuga-Escape-Lift-Kit/112460641185?epid=19025000547&hash=item1a2f2d33a1:g:0IYAAOSw1m9atFcz. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The highlighted text is what I am trying to get using the div id: `ds_div`. However When I debug it it has no value. Here is my code:

```
$description = $html->find("div[id=ds_div]", 0);
var_dump($description);
if($description != null){
$item['description'] = $description->plaintext;
}else{
    $item['description'] = '';
}
```

Comment: In your screenshot it says `div#desc_div`, but you're getting `div[id=ds_div]`?

Comment: The id which I took is `ds_div`, like the one on the upper right corner of the screenshot

Comment: There is no element with id `ds_div` on that page. Nothing found. That's why you get nothing

Comment: Is this div under the <td> tag?

Comment: yes,  it is under it and under the `<tbody>` tag

Comment: No, it isn't. As I said, there is no element with id `ds_div` on that page. Take a look at the source of that page and you'll see that the description is actually in an `iframe` with a different URL - which contains an element with id `ds_div`. Use the URL of the `iframe` to check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There actually is no element with id `ds_div` on that page, that's why your query returns nothing. There is however an `iframe` on that page that contains the element you're looking for. Get the URL of that `iframe`, parse/scrape the source of that and you should get your description.

Comment: `$description = $html->find("iframe[id=desc_ifr]", 0);`        
 `$item['description'] = $description->src;` But how to get the content inside the link which I got by this way?

Comment: That would be subject for a new question

Answer (score 0):

Try this May be this will helps to you,

```
foreach ( $html->find('td div#ds_div') as $element ) {
  echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
}
```